# Proving $ \sum \frac{a(b+c)}{a^2+bc}+\frac{2\sum (a^2-bc)}{(a+b+c)^2}+\frac{96(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2}{(a+b+c)^6} \leqslant \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca} $

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

For $a,b,c>0.$ Prove$:$ $$\displaystyle \frac{a(b+c)}{a^2+bc}+\frac{b(c+a)}{b^2+ca}+\frac{c(a+b)}{c^2+ab} +\frac{2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)}{(a+b+c)^2}+\frac{96(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2}{(a+b+c)^6} \leqslant \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab+bc+ca} $$
I found it when I tried to find the stronger version of [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2049439p14548705), you can see my post in #4.

This is true, which is verify by Maple. So I tried to get in pqr form, but it's so hard.
$$20736\,q{r}^{4}+96\,pq \left( 59\,{p}^{2}-306\,q \right) {r}^{3}+ \left( 8\,{p}^{8}+380\,{p}^{6}q-3984\,{p}^{4}{q}^{2}+9600\,{p}^{2}{q} ^{3}+5664\,{q}^{4} \right) {r}^{2}+p \left( {p}^{10}-6\,{p}^{8}q+11\,{ p}^{6}{q}^{2}-132\,{p}^{4}{q}^{3}+1344\,{p}^{2}{q}^{4}-4032\,{q}^{5} \right) r+6\,{q}^{5} \left( {p}^{2}-8\,q \right) ^{2} \geqslant 0,$$
Where $p=a+b+c,q=ab+bc+ca,r=abc.$

BW kills it immediately but it's not available with no computer.

So I hope to another solution. Of course, except BW, any solution are welcome here include SOS.

Thanks for a real lot!

Comment: Yes, by BW it's obvious.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg but I don't think BW is a nice solution. Does $uvw$ can kills it?

Comment: @tthnew BW is nice when there is no solution by hand.

Comment: @tthnew pqr method may work. We need to eliminate $r$.

Comment: @RiverLi Could you show your pqr solution or SOS. I can't not find SOS for this. BW give a SOS but not the standard.

Comment: @tthnew I gave a pqr solution to your another question. Please take a look if it is helpful. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661036/proving-a2b2c2-frac1a2-frac1b2-frac1c2-frac486ab/3789713#3789713

Comment: @tthnew  I do not have a pqr solution or SOS.